# Why ReactDnD plugin is not working in IE browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer, react-dnd

I'm using [ReactDnd](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/examples/dustbin/single-target) for my drag and drop functionality in my new project which works perfectly.

It works perfectly in Chrome and firefox, things turned worse when I've checked it in IE. It throws error while opening page/while page loading.

Errors :

1. Symbol is not defined.

   ```
   *Symbol is undefined*
   *File: DndProvider.js, Line: 77, Column: 1*
   ```
2. Even the demo [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/react-dnd/react-dnd/tree/gh-pages/examples_hooks_js/01-dustbin/single-target?from-embed) is not working in IE which is listed in official React Dnd page.

Almost, i have finished the functionality with React Dnd, now I struggled to put it in production since it throws errors in IE. Anyone, please help me on this, What I have to do to get this work on IE.

additional link to follow ie realted : https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd-html5-backend/commit/295805cbeecb1b7544de241a9e6a5ee4dd0e3134

Answer (score 0):

ReactDnd does not have support for IE. You may want to implement a check for IE in your code and put a popup saying to use another browser if the user is using IE.

Comment: it gives me heartache, since many users using IE still, I need to get this work since i have finished all of the functionality with this plugin. Can you check this once https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/issues/199 .. Dan Abramov has stated that We strive to support the evergreen browsers, Safari 7+, as well as IE11+. IE10 should also work

Answer (score 0):

Your sandbox code link shows blank page in Internet Explorer 11 browser but the example on it's official page is running fine in IE 11.

Here is a testing result.

[image]

I tested on IE 11 (11.1.18362.0) version. I also tested it on IE 10 document mode and it worked fine.

If you are using any older version of IE browser then I suggest you to upgrade to IE 11 browser with its latest update and try to run the sample with it.

Comment: yes, codesandbox link will definitely shows as blank since it throws error.Can you check the codesandbox or the demo example link in codesandbox again